# Visual Studio 2008 connecting textboxes with database tables using table adapter

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2008, windows-mobile

I am trying to connect my UI elements with database tables through the table adapter. I have created a query to insert the data into the database, there are no errors but the database is not updating.

```
private void SaveBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string Bcode = InvTxt1.Text;
            string Cid = customerTxt.Text;
            string s = "notassign";
            DateTime Ctime = DateTime.Now;

            AppDatabase1DataSet ds = new AppDatabase1DataSet();
            AppDatabase1DataSet.orderTableDataTable dt = new AppDatabase1DataSet.orderTableDataTable();
            this.orderTableTableAdapter1.GetData();
            this.orderTableTableAdapter1.InsertQuery(@Bcode, @Cid, @s, @Ctime);
        }
```

Comment: try using orderTableTableAdapter1.Update(ds, "test");
 ds.AcceptChanges();

Comment: Where is Your Command and SQL String?

Comment: Yes, you have to update all connected objects (adapter, table, database). Or you perform 'direct' (ExecuteNonQuery) SQL commands to update the databse, which will desync the database and your objects.

Comment: I can't really show you how to fix this without more code. What does your `INSERT` statement look like? Instead of a `DataAdapter`, why not just use an `SqlCommand`, populate your parameters, and call the `ExecuteNonQuery()` on it?